# Underfull \hbox with tikz node and align=right

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why do I get an underfull `\hbox` with this `tikz` node and how do I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, text width=6cm, align=right] {Some random text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Console output:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 5--5
 [][][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Some ran-dom text
```

It doesn't happen with `align=left` or `align=center`. The actual output looks fine.

Comment: I also do not know *why* that happens. An ad hoc way to get rid of the warning is to say `\node[draw, text width=6cm, align=right] {\hfill Some random text};`, i.e. add an `\hfill`. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is unavoidable. As explained in Section 17.4.3 of the [`PGF Man­ual`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf):

> **Page 225**: … If you specify a large line width and the node text fits on a single line and is, in fact, much shorter than the specified `text width`, an underfull horizontal box will result. Unfortunately, this cannot be avoided … Note that you may get annoying warnings for perfectly normal boxes, namely whenever the box is very large and the contents is not long enough to fill the box sufficiently.

To turn off the warning, you may issue an `\hfill` as already proposed by @marmot in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, text width=6cm, align=right] {\hfill Some random text};
\end{tikzpicture}\par
$\uparrow$\par
No underfull \texttt{\textbackslash hbox} badness!\par
\vspace{1ex}
\hrule\par
\vspace{1ex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \draw[latex-latex]
    (4,1.2) node[above] {Underfull \texttt{\textbackslash hbox} badness} --
    (4,0) --
    (6.2,0) node[right] {text width};
  \draw
    (4.0,0) --
    (4.3,0) --
    (4.4,0.1087) --
    (4.5,0.1308) --
    (4.6,0.1558) --
    (4.7,0.1845) --
    (4.8,0.2158) --
    (4.9,0.2503) --
    (5.0,0.2884) --
    (5.1,0.3312) --
    (5.2,0.3769) --
    (5.3,0.4266) --
    (5.4,0.4805) --
    (5.5,0.5403) --
    (5.6,0.6032) --
    (5.7,0.6708) --
    (5.8,0.7433) --
    (5.9,1) --
    (6.1,1);
  \foreach \index in {4,4.5,...,6}
    \draw (\index,0.05) -- (\index,-0.05) node[below] {\index\,cm};
  \foreach \index in {0,2000,...,10000}
    \draw (4.05,\index/10000) -- (4-0.05,\index/10000) node[left] {\index};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: badness vs. text width]